# Button stays in pressed state after OnTouch callback

Tags: android, android-button, ontouchlistener, compound-drawables

I'm defining a `CompoundDrawable` on a button and reacting for clicks on it:

```
    mFileSelector.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        final int DRAWABLE_LEFT = 0;
        final int DRAWABLE_TOP = 1;
        final int DRAWABLE_RIGHT = 2;
        final int DRAWABLE_BOTTOM = 3;

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            if (event.getRawX() >= (mFileSelector.getRight() - mFileSelector.getCompoundDrawables()[DRAWABLE_RIGHT].getBounds().width())) {
                mFileSelector.setSelected(false);
                mFileSelector.setPressed(false);
                mFileSelector.clearFocus();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

As you can see I've tried `setSelected`, `setPressed` and `clearFocus` but none of them did any good. The button stays in 'pressed' state after positive `onTouch` (meaning I consumed the touch event)

Comment: I just tested your code. The button reverts back to normal state as soon as I lift my finger. Are you overriding MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN also and not consuming it ?

Comment: @MayRestinPeace thank you for checking this out. That's all the relevant code. I guess the behavior changes between different versions/vendors as it usually do

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to change the background of your button, something like this will help you.

```
 if (enabled) {
        your_button?.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.round_button_blue)
    } else {
        your_button?.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.round_button_gray)
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. What should I use the background? (I need the default one)

Comment: The default one? create two drawables styles. Care to share some more code? I can update my answer

Comment: I use the default button design. I don't want to use custom drawables. What other code would assist?